# What is the way to stop the thread (when I directly inherit from QThread)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

**.h**

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void run()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            qDebug() << "\nsdfdsf";
        }
    }

public:
    MainWindow(QThread *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QThread *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

Now, this is an old way of working with threads, I know.
I want to know what is the way to stop the thread when working with method?

Please show the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt5, there is [interrupt request (`QThread::requestInterruption`)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) that can be handled by the thread, so there is an elegant and unified way to let the threads stop.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900622/104774).

Comment: What would be the way to call that? Directly like this: `QThread::requestInterruption`

Comment: Yes, followed by `QThread::wait()` and in the thread loop, check `QThread::isInterruptionRequested()`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to replace `while(1)` with `while(someCondition)` where `someCondition` might stand for a simple boolean variable, a function you call or whatever else check is appropriate to determine if the thread should still be running.